# Datatable destroy not working properly

Tags: datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

After using table.destroy() method my table rows are still displayed, only the search box and other borders of datatable are not displayed.

I want to delete all the rows in the datatable, basically i want to delete the whole datatable so that i can reinitialize it.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `destroy()` method you are effectively returning the table back to its original state. The `HTML` for the table is still present on the page hence why you can still see the table rows, without the added `DataTables` functionality.

If you want to remove the data rows from your `DataTable`, you may want to look at the [clear()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear%28%29) method, for example:

```
table.clear();
```

I have set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdbb8uxp/) which demonstrates these options.

If you can provide your code I should be able to give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your reply, but the problem is I am still getting the column headers , and I am not able to load new columns.

Can you tell me what is going wrong?
And If I use table.destroy() twice continuously then I am not able to create table again. 

Thankyou

Comment: Shall I edit my question to give you brief detail of my problem

Comment: I would suggest that you destroy your original DataTable, refresh your table HTML, and then re-initialise your DataTable. See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pdbb8uxp/1/. If you can post your code I might be able to help more.

Comment: Note that the jsfiddle example given actually calls `table.clear().draw();`.  Just `table.clear()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else finds this thread, I had the same issue when trying to replace a datatable with an ajax call.  Calling destroy and then reinitializing the datatable after the ajax response worked for me with no errors. [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy())

```
$('#myTrigger').click(function(e){        
    e.preventDefault();  

    table.destroy();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'processor.php',
        data: $('#myform').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {                        
            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "pageLength": 25
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```